# How do I pass multiple "bq" arguments to LocalParams in SolrNet?

Tags: solrnet

`LocalParams` is really just a `Dictionary<string, string>` behind the scenes.

However, I want to pass multiple Boost Queries, which use the key "bq".  Obviously, any attempt to add my second "bq" key will fail with `An item with the same key has already been added.`

```
var lp = new LocalParams();
lp.Add("bq", "ContentType:Update^3.0");
lp.Add("bq", "ContentType:Comment^0.5"); // Error occurs here...
```

What's the trick to passing multiple Boost Queries (or multiple anything, really)...

Comment: `bq` should not be in a `LocalParams`, it's not valid Solr syntax. Use the `ExtraParams` property instead.

Comment: I still have the same problem -- `ExtraParams` is a `Dictionary<string, string>()`, so I can't have two entries with the same key.

Comment: Created a FAQ entry about this: https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/master/Documentation/FAQ.md#whats-the-difference-between-localparams-and-extraparams

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment above set me onto ExtraParams.

I thought it wouldn't work since that was a `Dictionary<string, string>` (thus leaving me in the same situation), but the [actual property definition](https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/master/SolrNet/Commands/Parameters/CommonQueryOptions.cs#L61) is `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`. It's just set to a `Dictionary<string,string>` in the constructor.

So I did this:

```
var extraParams = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
extraParams.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("bq", "SomeQuery^10"));
extraParams.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("bq", "SomeOtherQuery^10"));

var options new new QueryOptions();
options.ExtraParams = extraParams; //Since my List implements the right interface

solr.Query(myQuery, options)
```

My testing shows that it works as intended.